# how to access $_SESSION variable in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am trying to do the following:

```
        $postfields = array_merge($_SERVER, array("p"=>$_POST, "s"=>$_SESSION));
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postfields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

why isn't this working? It always gives me an error that $_SESSION does not exist.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony uses a special session library that extends the PHP `$_SESSION` interface. To access all of the session attributes as a `key => value` array, you can use (from any controller/container):

```
$all_session_variables = $this->get('session')->all(); // Returns array() format
```

Or a specific session element using:

```
$key_session_variable = $this->get('session')->get('key'); // Returns the value stored in "key"
```

But this is only guaranteed to work assuming that you've previously set session variables using `$this->get('session')->set()`.

[Read more about Session Management here in the Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Onto why you are getting a "`$_SESSION` does not exist" error: you haven't declared `session_start()`! Symfony hasn't done that for you either yet. But **WAIT**. Do **NOT** write that code since the same reference above states:

> Symfony sessions are designed to replace several native PHP functions. Applications should avoid using `session_start()`, `session_regenerate_id()`, `session_id()`, `session_name()`, and `session_destroy()` and instead use the APIs in the following section.

You should instead use the Session library that Symfony provides because:

> While it is recommended to explicitly start a session, a sessions will actually start on demand, that is, if any session request is made to read/write session data.

Answer (score 1):

To get session try this into your controler :

```
$session = $this->get('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

the recommended way (in controller):

```
...

public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
}

...
```

or by injecting `RequestStack` (in CustomService):

```
private $requestStack;

public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
}

public function myMethod()
{
    $session = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
}
```